# woocommerce place order with multiple payment methods

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to place order with different payment methods in woocommerce?

For example I have some products with only "COD" method and some products with both "COD and Online payment"  option.

While user pays for this order via Online payment method, It need to calculate only the Online payable products, and user pay for it. and other must be calculated as  Cash on dilivery. This need to happen at once.

Is there any plugin or way around to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.
At once you can't pay the order with multiple payment gateways.
But you can show/hide payment gateways depending on condition like, what products are there in your cart.